# How to couple a differential equation with a normal equation?

Tags: python, ode, differential-equations, linear-equation

My problem is the following: I have a differential equation for X in dependence of z, dXdz. This equation depends on a Temperature T. This temperature T depends on dXdz in a seperate equation, equation 2. Technically, I could calculate the derivative dXdz based on the value of T, and then calculate the next value of T based on the second equation.

My question is, how do I implement this? For dXdz, I can implement the solve_ivp function from SciPy. But how can I implement the second equation?

Comment: You could calculate the derivative `dx/dz` based on the value of `T`, and then calculate the next value of `T` based on the second equation.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.